# SignedXml with Azure Keyvault SignData

Tags: azure, .net-core, cryptography

I know how to sign a XML document using SignedXml (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

I know how to sign data using Azure KeyVault API so the private key keeps secured (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.cryptographyclient.signdata?view=azure-dotnet)

Now I want to combine both, use SignedXml (or creating same result), using the key in the vault without extracting the private key.

Trying to set both values as displayed below does not seem to be correct

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
                <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
</Signature>
```

```
var digestValue = new SHA256Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xmlDoc.OuterXml));
var signatureValue = new CryptographyClient().SignData(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, digestValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement custom class inherited from [`System.Security.Cryptography.RSA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03h9zcez(v=vs.110).aspx) class, use KeyVault API in its implementation and then use instance of your custom class as a [`SigningKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.signingkey(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can implement it yourself or you can use [RSAKeyVaultProvider](https://github.com/novotnyllc/RSAKeyVaultProvider) library.

Comment: I did get it working by manually creating the signinfo class and properly canonicalize it (here was the main issue before)
But this is much cleaner, thanks!
I only had to override SignHash

Answer (score 0):

```
SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(tokenDoc);
var reference = new Reference("");
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
signedXml.AddReference(reference);
signedXml.SigningKey = new KeyVaultRsa();
signedXml.ComputeSignature();
var xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
```

```
internal class KeyVaultRsa : RSA
{
    public override RSAParameters ExportParameters(bool includePrivateParameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override byte[] SignHash(byte[] hash, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
    {
        var keyId = new Uri("https://xxx.vault.azure.net/keys/xxx");
        var rsaCryptoClient = new Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography.CryptographyClient(keyId, new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential());
        var result = rsaCryptoClient.Sign(Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography.SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, hash);

        return result.Signature;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).